# Problems when using Bootstrap toggle in angular 2.0 after setting up MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angular, express, twitter-bootstrap-3

I followed a tutorial to set up what I need for a MEAN stack app and its went well so far but now I've tried testing some of the bootstrap components from there site after installing Bootstrap in the index.html file for Angular, Bootstrap is being loaded as the font of the text that the app first loads is different and the drop down button appears after adding it but the problem is when I try click the drop down button nothing happens, besides that components like a jumbotron load as usual and look how you would expect in Bootstrap so I dont think its the link in index or bower.

Heres the index.html file:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>MyTaskList</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
   </head>
   <!-- 3. Display the application -->
   <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
   </body>
</html>
```

Heres the html it loads in with the bootstrap applied:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">


</head>

<body>

    <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just added Bootstrap css in the html.So only css changes will reflect.To get full functionality of Bootstrap you need to add **Bootstrap.js** and **JQuery**. Without them bootstrap is incomplete.